# Limit AutoresizingMask height stretch

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I made this screen

[Screen on iPhone 4s(9.3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H75PV.png)

It looks fine on that device, however when i test this same screen with iPhone6(9.3) it looks like this. **Since i cannot post more than 2 links, i merged the third image with the second one**

[Screen on iPhone 6(9.3) with the Third Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wisdU.png)

As you can see, that gray view, doesn't fill the white space beetwen that same gray view and the first bottom button(**lojas**). Notice that i don't have the autoresizing height stretch on(that vertical arrow inside the blocks). If i turn that on, this happens

**Third Image inside the Second Image**

See that, the gray view goes over the buttons, i don't want that.

My question is, how can i solve this? Is there a way to make the gray view stop above the Lojas Buttom at the bottom? Thanks for your time!

**OBS: I CANNOT use autolayout.**

**EDIT: Got the problem solved**

I just changed the **View as** option in Interface Builder, changed it to 7.0 and later, so it gave me the "real appareance" of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the **View as** option inside the **Interface Builder** so i could see how the app really look like and set the iOS Deltas to 0, made the changes based on that.